# I tried this code to print out prime numbers up to a given amount, but I keep running into bugs

Tags: sh, echo

I tried this code to print out the prime numbers up to a given amount, but i keep running into bugs

```
echo "enter range: "
read n
echo "prime no are:"
m=2
while [ $m -le $n ] do
i=2 flag=0
while [ $i -le `expr $m/2` ] do
if [ `expr $m % $i` -eq 0 ] then
flag=1 break fi
i= `expr $i +1`
then
if [ $flag -eq 0 ]
then echo $m fi
    m= `expr $m + 1`

done
```

I tried searching through google, but in the end, I don't understand the proper syntax, and I am hoping someone can help

Comment: For starters, paste your code into https://shellcheck.net and include `#!/bin/sh` as the fist line. (I'd recommend joining the 90's and use `#!/bin/bash` instead, but you have tagged your question with `[sh]`.) Fix all flagged issues if that doesn't help you solve your problem, update your question above with the corrected code and add a comment like "#shellcheck approved code".

Comment: If you can use `#!/bin/bash` instead, then learn about `(if/while) (( .... )) ; then/do` to replace your use of back-tics command substitution inside logic tests. The `((....))` part is called arithmetic evaluation and has a related syntax, arithmetic substitution (not applicable to your problem now) that looks like `$(( .... ))`  (note the leading `$` char). Replace back-tic cmd-substitution with "modern 1988" style cmd substitution that looks like `$( cmd_that_outputs_text/nums )`. This can be used like `var=$(cmd_outputs_text/nums)`. ... Search for the bashFAQ .

Comment: you can stop before m/2, you only need to count until sqrt(m)

Answer (score 1):

You can write really clean code. Just use some indentation. Also, I used the plain algorithm for finding prime numbers from 1 to N:

- for each element, i, from 1 to N, compute it's square root
- find factors of i, if factor count is `>= 1`, then it's not prime, else prime.

```
echo -n "enter range: "
read n
if [ $n -le 1 ]
then
        echo "No prime numbers found"
        exit 0
fi

echo -n "prime no are:"
if [ $n -eq 2 ]
then
        echo -ne " 2\n"
        exit 0
fi
i=2
while [ $i -le $n ]
do
        j=2
        factors=0
        sqrt_i=`echo $i | awk '{printf int(sqrt($1))}'`
        #echo "Sqrt of $i is $sqrt_i"
        while [ $j -le $sqrt_i ]
        do
                if [ `expr $i % $j` -eq 0 ]
                then
                        factors=`expr $factors + 1`
                fi
                j=`expr $j + 1`
        done
        #echo "Number of factors: $factors"
        if [ $factors -eq 0 ]
        then
                echo -n " $i"
        fi
        i=`expr $i + 1`
done
echo ""
```

Comment: If nothing else, this demonstrates why POSIX `sh` is not a good tool for this.